# CodenameOne: convert smartphone / tablet app to Linux desktop app

Tags: java, linux, cross-platform, codenameone

I've written an app that works fine in the Codename One simulator (on smartphone and tablet Android / iOS virtual devices).

Now I need to make it a Linux desktop application. According to the web page "[How Do I - Create A Desktop Application With Codename One?](https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---create-a-desktop-application-with-codename-one.html)", the automatic conversion to a desktop app is available only for Windows and Mac (for paid users).

Is there any way to convert my app to a Linux executable, also manually? For semplicity, I don't need an installer and I can assume that the target Linux machines have JRE installed.

Thank you very much for any help.

P.S.: If I need a Codename PRO account, I have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently we don't have a dedicated Linux target because the target is so problematic with Linux VM's however if you build a Windows or Mac target the JAR file that we generate is within. You can just install the Windows or Mac target and open it up to extract the JAR from there.

If there is enough user demand we might offer a standardized JAR target.

Comment: Thank you, I've done as you suggested: I've copied the "app" directory (installed on a Windows target) to a Linux machine and I was able to run the main jar.